# Can i pass a function as an argument on the command line on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, command-line-arguments

So we have a python code that we execute on the command line with some arguments
`py code.py -p1 a -p2 b`. Now we need to pass a date as an argument using a function, is there any way to write something like `py code.py -p1 a -p2 b -p3 datetime.date.now()`.

My boss is awsking if we can do this but i have searched and found nothing.
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Your shell is not executing python commands.

You can however use your shell capabilities to generate the date, for example with [sh](/questions/tagged/sh)/[bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
py code.py -p1 a -p2 b -p3 $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
```

Would launch the command:

```
py code.py -p1 a -p2 b -p3 2023-01-12
```

Another possibility is to pass `now` as parameter and to handle it in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but beware that it's a big security risk.  It will run **any** code entered at the command line.

```
text = eval(parameter)
```